# How can I use a ComboBox number to add to a date text box?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm working on a project and I need to use a `ComboBox`  to select the number of days I wanna use in the query to add to the date selected. Its purpose is to limit the range of days the user will be able to use on the search so the form won't take too long to load. I've been trying to use `DateAdd` and it's not working. Is there any other way to do it? The code I'm using for the Query is below.

- `dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta` is my table from SQL Server, linked to Access.
- `Indicadores` is the name of my form.
- The `ComboBox` with the numbers (from 1 to 7, the days) is `Combinação72`.

```sql
SELECT
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.area,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_abertura,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_termino,
    CStr(dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.ia) AS ia,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_est_termino,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_atuacao,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.atividade,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.ocorrencia,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.fase,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.org,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.chpras,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.conta_cartao,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.cartao,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.jornada,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.tipo2,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.subjornada,
    dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.assunto,
    [teste] AS Expr1 INTO dados_export
FROM dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta
WHERE (((dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.area)=Forms!Indicadores!Area)
And ((dbo_temp_aof_reativos_ferramenta.data_abertura)
Between (Forms!Indicadores!DATAIN)
And (([teste])=DateAdd("d",Forms!Indicadores!Combinação72,"DATAIN"))));
```

Right now, when I try to use this code, Access asks me to save a backup and shuts down.

Comment: hi. try to change "d" to 'd' and "DATAIN" to 'DATAIN'. good luck

Comment: Hi Luis Curado, I tried this and it gives me an error message: Incompatible data type in criterion expression.